# How do I check if object exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this firestore document and I wanted to check if `doses` exist in the document since there are other documents that do not have the `doses` yet. Hence, retrieving the data inside the `doses` will cause an error.

[image]

This is how I retrieve the specific document:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });

        setUsers(arr);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

To display the data inside the `doses`. This will only work if `doses` exist in the document. For other users that does not have this object yet, it would cause an error that says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedVaccine' of undefined

```
  {users && users.map((user) => {
             {user.doses.selectedVaccine}    
              })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `optional chaining` to avoid this issue like this

```
{user.doses?.selectedVaccine}
```

Comment: what if I was checking each document inside the user collection if the object `doses` exist? How would I check it?

Comment: if the object doses exist, it will continue run to find `selectedVaccine`